# PHP changes not updating on live site

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, updating

I'm working on a WordPress installation hosted by HostGator. I have added new code to a php file which is used for the home page gallery slider. The changes work on my local installation but do not appear on the live site. I have even attempted to insert gibberish code into the file to see if it would update, It did not. This leads me to believe it's being cached somewhere and not updating.

I have disabled all suspected caching plugins.

Added `define('DISABLE_CACHE', true);` to wp-config.php

Cleared all browser caches, and CTR + F5

Verified the code is sound

Waited overnight to see if it would update eventually

STATUS UPDATE:
I've continued to do the steps I've outlined above. I've had suggestions that it may not be the correct file that I am editing. The problem with that assumption, is that it works fine on the local host test site, just not on the live. If anyone has suggestions in that regard it would be helpful as well.

UPDATE 2:
I'm attempting to determine if my Instant Wordpress 4.3.1 runs a different php version than HostGator (php 5.2.17) but I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: If you "disabled all suspected caching plugins", then I would presume you had one (or more) activated?  Certain cache plugins would require you to clear the cache prior to disabling them. You should reactivate and make sure you have properly cleared the cache there before disabling.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I've cleared the caches properly. Multiple times. W3 Total Cache is the main plugin.

Comment: Did someon find the problem ?